# How to apply sigmoid function for each outputs in Keras?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, sigmoid

This is part of my codes.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(3, input_shape=(4,), activation='softmax'))
model.compile(Adam(lr=0.1),
          loss='categorical_crossentropy',
          metrics=['accuracy'])
```

with this code, it will apply softmax to all the outputs at once. So the output indicates probability among all. However, I am working on non-exclusive classifire, which means I want the outputs to have independent probability.
Sorry my English is bad...
But what I want to do is to apply sigmoid function to each outputs so that they will have independent probabilities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using Functional API to create a model with n outputs where each output is activated with `sigmoid`.

You can do it like this

```
in = Input(shape=(4, ))

dense_1 = Dense(units=4, activation='relu')(in)

out_1 = Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid')(dense_1)
out_2 = Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid')(dense_1)
out_3 = Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid')(dense_1)

model = Model(inputs=[in], outputs=[out_1, out_2, out_3])
```

Answer (score 7):

*There is no need to create 3 separate outputs like suggested by the accepted answer.*

**The same result can be achieved with just one line:**

```
model.add(Dense(3, input_shape=(4,), activation='sigmoid'))
```

---

You can just use `'sigmoid'` activation for the last layer:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import GRU
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation
import numpy as np

from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(3, input_shape=(4,), activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(Adam(lr=0.1),
          loss='categorical_crossentropy',
          metrics=['accuracy'])

pred = model.predict(np.random.rand(5, 4))
print(pred)
```

***Output of independent probabilities:***

```
[[0.58463055 0.53531045 0.51800555]
 [0.56402034 0.51676977 0.506389  ]
 [0.665879   0.58982867 0.5555959 ]
 [0.66690147 0.57951677 0.5439698 ]
 [0.56204814 0.54893976 0.5488999 ]]
```

---

As you can see the classes probabilities are independent from each other. The sigmoid is applied to every class separately.

Comment: Wow I see. I think I was confused between Sigmoid and softmax... If I use softmax, it not going to be independent probabilities,right? I just need to use sigmoid.

Comment: Exactly - softmax gives you a probability distribution over all outputs while sigmoid just maps your outputs to a value between 0 and 1. But independent for each value. Therefore there is no need to do so like suggested by the answer of 'Sreeram TP'. Just using sigmoid will give you the same result.

Comment: My independent probability is not increasing in sigmoid([0.08844085 0.00417994]). Using softmax I get correct result. Changing it into softmax ([0.98502016 0.0149798 ]). WHy its not performing good in sigmoid?

Comment: @GiriAnnamalaiM Softmax and Sigmoid are two completely different functions serving entirely different purposes. Explaining the difference is too much for a comment. I strongly suggest that you read a bit more about Sigmoid and Softmax and try to understand the difference. If you still stuck you can ask a question here, including the necessary detail of your problem!

Comment: @blue-phoenox I opened a question regarding this. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55469601/increase-sigmoid-prediction-output-values