# Increase sigmoid prediction output values?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I created a Conv1D model for text classification.

When using softmax / sigmoid at the last dense, It yields result as

```
softmax => [0.98502016 0.0149798 ]
sigmoid => [0.03902826 0.00037046]
```

I just want the sigmoid result's first index **should be at least greater than 0.8**. Just want the multi-classes should have independent results. How do I achieve this?

Model summary:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding (Embedding)        (None, 128, 100)          600       
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d (Conv1D)              (None, 126, 128)          38528     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d (MaxPooling1D) (None, 63, 128)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_1 (Conv1D)            (None, 61, 128)           49280     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_1 (MaxPooling1 (None, 30, 128)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_2 (Conv1D)            (None, 28, 128)           49280     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_2 (MaxPooling1 (None, 14, 128)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 1792)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 2)                 3586      
=================================================================
Total params: 141,274
Trainable params: 141,274
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(num_class, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['acc'])
```

Comment: I haven't used keras in a while, but I think you need to use a different loss function with `sigmoid`, as `categorical_crossentropy` is used for depended classes. So probably `binary_crossentropy` should work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with comment by @blue-phoenox that you shouldn't use sigmoid with cross-entropy because the sum of probabilities of classes does not equal one. But if you have reasons for using `sigmoid`, you can normalize your output by the sum of the vector elements to make it equal to 1:

```
output = output/tf.reshape(tf.reduce_sum(output, 1), (-1, 1))
```

And you'll get:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

output = tf.Variable([[0.03902826, 0.00037046]])
output = output/tf.reshape(tf.reduce_sum(output, 1), (-1, 1))
summedup = tf.reduce_sum(output, axis=1)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(output.eval()) # [[0.9905971  0.00940284]] - new output
    print(summedup.eval()) # [1.] -  summs up to 1
```

To implement it in `keras` you can create a subclass of `tf.keras.layers.Layer` like this:

```py
from tensorflow.keras import layers

class NormLayer(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(NormLayer, self).__init__()

    def call(self, inputs):
        return inputs / tf.reshape(tf.reduce_sum(inputs, 1), (-1, 1))
```

And then use it within your `Sequential()` model:

```py
# using dummy data to illustrate
x_train = np.array([[-1.551, -1.469], [1.022, 1.664]], dtype=np.float32)
y_train = np.array([[0, 1], [1, 0]], dtype=np.int32)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=2, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid, input_shape=(2, )))
model.add(NormLayer())

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x=x_train,
          y=y_train,
          epochs=2,
          batch_size=2)
# ...
```

Comment: Summing upto 1 means it goes like softmax.

I changed the entropy to categorical.
Output., [0.25759184 0.00109715 0.09936374 0.04078476]
The output should all values should greater than 0.5

Comment: `How do I apply this with predicted result?` - what do you mean? How do you apply it in keras?

Comment: `Summing upto 1 means it goes like softmax. ` - Not exactly. In a sense that probabilities summs up to 1 - yes. But the functions and derivative are different.

Comment: You are right. I applied this function with the result. All of them yielding 1. means, sigmoid with binary_crossentropy is returning sum of 1 as similar to softmax

Comment: Ok Both are different derivatives. In that case, how do we extract each class probabilities without affecting one another? Adjusting layer can solve this issue? Last layer is returning the probabilities of them.

Comment: @GiriAnnamalaiM If you divide by the vector's sum you just scaling up the values. What do you mean by *affecting one another*?

Comment: I meant the sum of all probabilities are equal to 1. So, I guess its affection one another>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191084/discussion-between-vlad-and-giri-annamalai-m).

Answer (score 1):

Sigmoid produces output between 0 and 1. If you are using the same loss function for both softmax and sigmoid then it won't work. Try binary_crossentropy instead. And if you have more than 2 classes I don't think sigmoid is what you are looking for.

Comment: I have 10 classes and need independent of each classes probability result. So I can't use binary_crossentropy?

Comment: I tried binary_crossentropy. The sum of predicted probabilities are equal to 1. Any way to alter the last dense to get the each class independent probabilities? @melowgs

Comment: Technically you could use your densr layer with 10 neurons (if you have 10 classes) and sigmoid function. But that's pretty much the same as softmax i think.

Comment: lets try that too

Comment: It's yielding result like this. The accuracy is not improving with single layer. [0.3011694  0.3035295  0.19065315 0.20597214]
0.3011 should be 0.85 or more than that